# Magento 2 Order View Rest API

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

I do want Order details/view rest API which is `"rest/V1/orders/1"` with image URL of products in an Order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**rest/V1/orders/1** does not provide the Product image, You have to  implement extension attribute on `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface`.

Create a module.On that module create at `{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/extension_attributes.xml` and code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="product_image" type="string">
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

After that create pLugin class on `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface`.
So, defined plugin class on  `di.xml` at `{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_Magento_Plugin_Magento_Sales_Api_Data_OrderItemInterface" 
            sortOrder="10" type="{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\OrderItemPlugin"/>
</type>
</config>
```

**Define Plugin class** at `{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Plugin/OrderItemPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;


class OrderItemPlugin {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory
     */
    private $orderItemExtensionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory $orderItemExtensionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager     
    ) {
        
        $this->orderItemExtensionFactory = $orderItemExtensionFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function afterGetExtensionAttributes(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        
        $imageUrl = $this->getProductImage($subject);
        if(!$imageUrl){
            return $result;
        }
        
        if($result=== null){
            $orderItemExtension =$this->orderItemExtensionFactory->create();
            $orderItemExtension->setProductImage($imageUrl);
            $subject->setExtensionAttributes($orderItemExtension);
        }else{
            $result->setProductImage($imageUrl);
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
    
    private function getProductImage($orderItem)
    {
        
        $productId = $orderItem->getProductId();
        $storeId = $orderItem->getStoreId();
        
        if($productId === null || $storeId === null){
            return false;
        }
        
        try{
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
            return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)
                    .'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $ex) {
            
        }
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$adminData = array("username" => "admin_username", "password" => "admin_password");

$ch = curl_init("http://siteurl/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($adminData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($adminData))));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
echo $token;
curl_close($ch); 


//Order collection Rest API
$request = "http://siteurl/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all";
$ch = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: yes Amit is correct it will not work I already tried.