# Magento2: How to add extension attribute to rest/V1/products/attribute-sets/4/attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, rest-api, extension-attributes

I want to add extension attribute to the default API to identify the visual and text swatches `http://localhost/m2.4/rest/V1/products/attribute-sets/4/attributes` API.

Answer (score 0):

@adi Please see this below link

[Answered](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/288259/magento-2-order-view-rest-api)

Follow the steps as mentioned and replace

> Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface to Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface

It will work

Change the code as required

Comment: its not working for me as i needed for rest/V1/products/attribute-sets/4/attributes API

Comment: @adimaheshwary I edit my answer please look into it.